# jQuery: live('focus') and live('blur') nested in a namespace not working in 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I've got the following html

```
<input class="hasToolTip" type="text" value="meh"/>
<span class="tooltip" style="display: none;">tooltip here</span>
```

i'd like the tooltip to fade in when the input gets focus, so i created a namespace (it contains all my javascript for inputs/forms in the following way) with the correct method

```
var inputCommon = (function() {
    return {
        SetupToolTips: function() {
            $(".hasToolTip").live('focus', function() {
                $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeIn();
            });
            $(".hasToolTip").live('blur', function() {
                $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeOut();
            });
        }
    };

})();
```

I then call it when the document is loaded

```
$(function() {
    inputCommon.SetupToolTips();
});
```

And... [it doesn't work with jQuery 1.3.2](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5uYsh/8/). [It works with 1.4.2](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5uYsh/9/) though, but i'm really ready to push a library change at the moment.

Any idea how i can have my cake (namespace!) and eat it too (live working!)?

---

Not one to resist making a fool of myself, here is the explicit excerpt i had skipped, [straight from the horse's mouth](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> In jQuery 1.3.x **only the following JavaScript events** (in
>   addition to custom events) could be
>   bound with .live(): click, dblclick,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown,
>   mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and
>   mouseup.
>
> (...)
>
> As of jQuery 1.4.1 **even focus and blur work with live** (mapping
>   to the more appropriate, bubbling,
>   events focusin and focusout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really, not without some *serious* changes that would likely introduce more issues than upgrading to 1.4+ would.  The event system got a huge overhaul in 1.4.2, and further refinements since then...your time would be much better spent on upgrading to jQuery 1.4+ than trying to work support for this into 1.3.x.

Comment: any specific things i should watch out for? The Changelogs (http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) are not really informative regarding potential breaking changes (if there are any)

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it this way...

```
var inputCommon = (function() {
    return {
        SetupToolTips: function() {
            $(".hasToolTip").focus(function() {
                $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeIn();
            });
            $(".hasToolTip").blur(function() {
                $(this).next(".tooltip").fadeOut();
            });
        }
    };

})();
```

rather than using live.

Comment: yeah, i know, that's what i'm using at the moment but i would really have liked eating the cake :)

Comment: yeah... then i would agree with nick in that it's just time to upgrade to 1.4+